# cannot find symbol addJavascriptInterface

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to get return value from java script to the java file in Cordova 6.2.0. For this i'm using the following code

```
JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(context);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");
webView.loadUrl("javascript:playVideo('" + something + "')");
```

---

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    private Context context;

    public JavaScriptInterface(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void startVideo(String videoAddress){
    }
}
```

---

```
<script>
    window.playVideo = function(video){
        window.JSInterface.startVideo(video);
    }
</script>
```

When i'm using this, i got error `cannot find symbol addJavascriptInterface` and tried to solve this by following these solutions

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28862780/3142611)

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    private Context context;

    @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface") // I've added this
    public JavaScriptInterface(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void startVideo(String videoAddress){
    }
}
```

[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30109668/3142611)

```
WebView wV = (WebView)appView.getEngine().getView();
```

But i didn't get the solution for this problem. Any one know how to handle this...

**Edit**

As listed in Source 2 i don't have `appView` to use

Answer (score 0):

When creating Cordova apps, the java-javascript communication should be done using plugins, read the [plugin development guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html)

In javascript you call it java function like this:

```
cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "videoplayer", "start",["videourl"]);
```

Then in your plugin java class add the execute method

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("start".equals(action)) {
        this.startVideo(args.getString(0));
        callbackContext.success();
        return true;
    }
    return false;  // Returning false results in a "MethodNotFound" error.
}

public void startVideo(String videoAddress){
}
```